# $filter if property does not exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm try to filter an array with this structure:

```
{
          "ordenes": [
            {
              "_id": "XXXX",
              "prop0": [{}],
              "prop1": [],
              "prop2": {},
              "prop3": {}
            },
            {
                "prop0": [{}],
                "prop1": [],
                "prop2": {},
                "prop3": {}
            }
          ]
}
```

Whit this code:

```
{
    "$project": {
       "moreProp": "$moreProp" ,
       "ordenes": {
            "$filter": {
               "input": "$ordenes",
               "as": "orden",
               "cond": { "$ifNull": ["$$orden._id", true] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to ignore elements from the array that not have the property `_id`, but its seems to not working with the code above.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problems I had to use the following condition:

```
{ $ifNull: ['$$orden._id', false]}
```

The `false` flag did the trick. For more info see this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5776).